# Update a csv file used by Quality Center with a macro

Tags: excel, csv, qtp, hp-quality-center, vba

I have a csv files containing iterations that will be imported into HP Quality Center and used to perform automated testing.

Some of the data in these files must be updated every month and I have created a macro for each to do this.

I cannot keep the macro and the csv on the one workbook as QC does not allow anything other than csv files to be imported (not that I know of).

I realise I can import the macro each time but there are many csv files and many macros.

Is there some format or work-around that would allow me to keep the macro on the csv file, so when I open it I can just hit Alt+F8 and run the macro?

Comment: a better approach might be to keep your macro and data in an excel file(s)... then add the step of saving your modified data as a csv to prep for upload each month.

Answer (score 0):

Save your macros in your personal workbook (personal.xslb), rather than in the individual data files. Then they will be available to run your updates on the csv files without being stored in the files.